# updateTime column default is not working with Spring Webflux and H2 R2DBC

Tags: reactive-programming, h2, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

Using Spring webflux with H2-R2DBC and creating a course by adding the details in course table defined as below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS course(
id VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
fee DECIMAL,
updatedtime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTMP);
```

Using ReactiveCrudRepository save method to save the data like below

```
Course course=new Course();
course.setName("Physics");
course.setId("PHY123");
course.fee(100);

repository.save(course);
```

as per logs in webflux on save the object is having null for updatedtime.

**Question :-**

1. How to avoid setting null and set default value as current timestamp on each insert/update.
2. How to use @Column(name="updatedtime",insertable=false) in Spring Webflux.

Comment: Try creating the table with `updatedTime TIMESTAMP AS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` im not sure it will work, something i remember i read once.

Comment: No, it's still set to null using AS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as well.

Comment: Alternatively , use the Spring data audit to fill the creation and update timestamp field, check [my example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/data-r2dbc-entitytemplate/src/main/java/com/example/demo/Post.java#L51).